# Would this be a valid proof for $\left| x + y \right| \geq \left| x \right| - \left| y \right|$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I wanted to check if this was a valid proof for considering whether $\left|x + y \right| \geq \left| x \right| - \left| y \right|$.

My proof is as follows:

*Case 1:* Assume $x > 0, y>0$,then $(x+y) > 0$
Hence $$(x+y) > x - y$$

*Case 2:* Assume $x<0 , y<0$
Hence, $-(x+y) = (-x) + (-y) = \left| x \right| + \left|y\right|$. $$\left| x \right| + \left| y \right| > \left| x \right| - \left| y \right|$$

*Case 3:* Assume without loss of generality where $x > 0, y < 0$.

**subcase: 1** $(x+y)\geq 0$. Hence, $$\left| x + y \right| = \left| x + y \right| = (x+y) = \left| x \right| - \left| y \right|$$

**subcase: 2** $(x+y) < 0$ where $\left| x + y \right| = -(x+y)$, hence, $$\left| x \right| + \left| y \right| = x - (-y) < (-x) + (-y) = \left| x + y \right|$$

I know this is a relatively simple proof but I am really trying to work on my proofs with real numbers which I am still not so good at and would like to confirm is this works because it seems different from the one thats provided in my solutions.

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This is a good proof! A perhaps simpler method is substituting $y \to -y$ and adding $|y|$ to both sides so that we have $|x-y| + |y| \geq |x|$ which follows from the triangle inequality.

Comment: Ah yes, is it the case that by doing this, one would not need to consider all 4 cases ? And as a side question, in proofs, would the triangle inequality be considered something that one needs to prove such as when adding a lemma or can it generally be considered as a very common theorem such that it is generally a "law". I see the simplicity of this method if it were to be that one does not need to prove the triangle inequality.

Comment: That depends. In my comment, I assume it is true because that's probably the most fundamental inequality pertaining to absolute values. It's generally easier to prove one theorem and then appeal to it (as a lemma) to prove other similar theorems than proving all of them from first principles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You type wrong just a signal.

**subcase 2:** $(x+y) < 0$ where $\mid x + y \mid = -(x+y)$, hence, 
$$\mid x \mid - \mid y \mid = x - (-y) < (-x) + (-y) = \mid x + y \mid$$

No more, everything is fine.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the check !